# Structuring angular service to facilitate data sharing across directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I have two directives - call them "mainPane" and "sidePane", each of which displays a list of items. The content of these two lists often overlaps - i.e. the same item is displayed in both lists - and the user can interact with items in either list. When the user changes something in an item in one list, I want it to be reflected immediately in the other list. That's my primary requirement.

I'm fairly certain that I want to store all my items in a `Content` service, where I'll also encapsulate the (AJAX) retrieval logic.

What I'm looking for is high-level advice about the best way to structure that service from there. Does it have two separate lists, one for each pane? If so, what do I do about items that are present in both? Storing all items in a single array and filtering it to produce the two separate lists is appealing, but unfortunately there's no inherent property of these items that determines which list they should appear in. I could make one, though - I could add an `onMainPane` and `onSidePane` field to these objects and filter on that. Is that the best way to go - and if so, should I do the filtering in the service or in the directives?

Or is there a better option?

Comment: Would be easier to assess with data samples. Hard to structure a data service with no idea what the data relationships are like. Some sort of `pane` property like you mentioned for filtering would definitely make your life simpler though

Answer (score 0):

Since you already creating `Content` service for encapsulation, leveraging that would be logical. `Content` service could be injected into the directive and share the list.

That being said, how large will be the lists? How complex will the directives/content items be? If the objects/directive are complex and the list large, the service route many not be suitable.